# How setup- and hold times affect the functionality of the FPGA implementation?

Tags: vhdl, hardware, fpga, digital

I am currently working on a VHDL module that first reads in the given input data in parallel via a shift register and then outputs the stored data bit by bit at the output in each clock cycle. For this I implemented a state machine that generates an SR_SHIFT_ENABLE strobe on the rising edge in every clock cycle, which then activates the shift register and creates another bit at the output. When rethinking my implementation, however, I had doubts about the later implementation on the FPGA.

In my current implementation, the generated SR_SHIFT_ENABLE strobe in the shift register is evaluated on the rising clock edge.[Enable Pulse is evaluated at the rising edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdi2m.png)

However, I'm wondering if in above simulation timing problems might occur in the FPGA implementation with this approach. Specifically, my concern is the SR_SHIFT_ENABLE pulse. According to the simulation, SR_SHIFT_ENABLE is evaluated by the shift register directly before its end.
However, according to my considerations, hold timing violations of the shift register could occur, so that this pulse on the rising edge is not present at the shift register long enough (hold time violation?).

One possibility would be to evaluate the SR_SHIFT_ENABLE pulse "in the middle" of the clock, i.e. at the falling clock edge.
[Enable Pulse is evaluated at the falling edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uID1Q.png)
In this way, I could ensure that no setup or hold timing violations occur (see simulation).

Since both alternatives work in the simulation, I would therefore like to know which of the two variants is preferable.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

I essentially tried two different implementations:

1. Sample the Enable signal on the rising edge which appears to be quite close to the end of this pulse (I expect hold time violations if no additional measures are undertaken)
2. Sample the Enable signal on the falling edge (Here I expect a more robust implementation, since the sampling point is located in the middle of the Enable pulse. Accordingly, the sampling point might not be strongly impacted by timing variations)

Since both implementations work, I would like to know which of these design alternatives is preferable.

Comment: Preferable without any criteria is subjective and lo and behold you got answers that are opinions. The question also doesn't appear to be about programming and certainly doesn't contain any VHDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1. If these signals are internal and your design is synchronous, don't worry about setup/hold time because FPGA tool will take care of it.

Case 2. If these signals are external (on the I/O pins of FPGA), you may set input/output delay on them in implementation to achieve timing requirement.

Case 3. If you don't know how to constrain input/output delay, then it's a good idea to toggle output on clock falling-edge and sample input on clock rising-edge.

However, case 3 sacrifices setup time margin for better hold time margin, which limits the maximum frequency of the I/O interface. But it's OK for low speed application.

Answer (score 0):

In a FPGA flow you will always define a clock frequency for your clock signal.
This enables the tools of the FPGA flow to check the routed netlist for setup- and hold-timing violations.

If your frequency is not a very fast one (for the selected FPGA device), the FPGA flow will normally reach timing closure,
this means there will be no setup- or hold-time violations left.

So the question is, which of your 2 ideas makes reaching timing closure easier:

When you use the falling clock edge at your shift-register, you create a path from the flipflop creating the SR_SHIFT_ENABLE
to the shift-register which has only half of the clock period time for the setup path. So setup-time fix is harder.
Of course, the hold-time fix is very easy in this case.

But as normally the setup-time fixes are the problematic ones in FPGA-designs, I recommend using the rising clock edge
for the shift register. Then you get a full clock period for the setup path of SR_SHIFT_ENABLE to the shift register.
The hold time fix is most of the time very easy, when the setup-path is relaxed, because then the hold-time-fix can easily
be done by delaying the signal (which makes the relaxed setup-path a little bit slower, which does not matter).